# Doctrine Subquery undefined class when using MIN and MAX

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am creating a query that identifies the previous and later record for a given ID. I have the following code:

```
$min = $this->createQueryBuilder('t1')
            ->select('MIN(t1.id)')
            ->where('t.id = t1.id' )
            ->andWhere('t1.id > :id')
            ->andWhere('t1.type = :type');

    $max = $this->createQueryBuilder('t2')
            ->select('MAX(t2.id)')
            ->where('t2.id > :id')
            ->andWhere('t2.type = :type')
            ->andWhere('t2.id = t.id');

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->addSelect('(' . $min->getDQL() . ') AS min')
        ->addSelect('(' . $max->getDQL() . ') AS max')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->setParameter('type', $type)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getScalarResult();
```

However the above code throws an error saying:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 138 near ', (SELECT MAX(t2.id)': Error: Class ',' is not defined.

Why is that so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is using `min` and `max` as alias. I got the same error when I used them, but changing the alias worked fine. I think you could also simplify your logic into one queryBuilder

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('story');

    $queryBuilder
        ->select('MAX(story.id) AS max_id')
        ->addSelect('MIN(story.id) AS min_id')
        ->where('story.id > :id')
        ->setParameter('id', 1);

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

Returned:

```
[
  {
    "max_id": "17",
    "min_id": "16"
  }
]
```